# How to protect open-source code?

Tags: licensing

I see that free licenses come with a "same license" and "disclose source" mentions, like stated [here](http://choosealicense.com/appendix/).

For instance, I have some software code under the GNU GPL v2 license on github. If some evil developer want to steal my code and use it in a closed-source software, how could I be aware of it, and how could I prove it since I don't have access to his source code ?

**Possible duplicate of [this question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/294790), but I find answers given here more interesting.**

Comment: You can't, any security mechanism you put in there can easily be circumvented.

Comment: @Matthew I'm not sure I understand. His question is how can he prove someone broke his license. I'm not sure what security has to do with that.

Comment: @VincentSavard, eg if the OP added a "this is open source software, did you get the source?" dialogue to his project, the "evil" developer could just remove it, looking for eg `MyGPLv2Project.dll` to see if it's being used is easily defeated by renaming the project to `MyClosedSourcedProject.dll` etc.

Comment: @DavidArno I'm not sure how you inferred that the author suggested this solution or thought this was the only solution.

Comment: @VincentSavard I may have misunderstood OP's question then, I read the "how could I be aware of it" as some sort of check within the open source software.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You would become aware of it through the advertising of EvilCorp ltd

Noticing that their new product had the same features as your Open source communist supporting software, you could purchase a copy of EvilCorps capitalistic version and then de-compile the source and look for code matching the signature of your own.

You could then sue them for billions and the court could compel them to release their source code and emails etc. Which would reveal their evil machinations!!

They would then be forced to put a link to the copied parts of the source code on their website INCLUDING an ASCII attribution with your github name and address in it.

Which no-one would ever look at.

Of course thats the best case scenario. Obviously EvilCorp would probably hire EvilLawyers(tm) and do all sorts of shady dealings to undermine your good name. You would probably be forced to go 'rogue' and join a secret underground 'cool' hacker collective. Together you would join forces to defeat EvilCorp and the shutdown MCP!!

Comment: "*you could purchase a copy of EvilCorps capitalistic version and then de-compile the source and look for code matching the signature of your own*" and you just broke the law in any country that forbid reverse engineering apps & Evil Corps lawyers would laugh you out of court (and then bill you for their costs).

Comment: ...its like EvilCorp monitor online forums and give out bad legal advice

Comment: @DavidArno This make sense, but then every license.md that you can find on github are basically useless ?

Comment: @DanChaltiel, As protection against evil folk stealing your code, pretty much, yes. Many people aren't evil though and will pay attention and do their best to comply.

Comment: unless you are also a massive corporation with the funds to sue oracle/google/ms